# Auto-generate a local variable in VS?

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2012, when an expression (with known type) is assigned to an undefined identifier (say: `xxxx=2;`) causing the compilation error *"The name 'xxxx' does not exist in the current context"*, the suggested fixes are `Generate property stub` and `Generate field stub`.

I wonder why there is no a similar `Generate local variable` option, and whether there is some shortcut so that I don't need to type it.

Comment: `Home` -> `v` -> `a` -> `r` -> `space`.

Comment: @Oded: Thanks. But I'd prefer to avoid avoid `var` , and have the explicit type.

Comment: You are not going to get this out of VS.  Resharper's "Introduce Variable" feature, maybe.

Comment: It's a pity, I excessively use this for Java development in Eclipse. You need to think and type less, and that's what coding is all about... :)